# Break loop in Firebase with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner Firebase and am having trouble breaking the loop. The code below looks at the recipe products and the quantity of products, if the inventory has enough products to make the recipe, the code triggers an alert stating that there are enough products, otherwise it triggers the alert saying that the products in stock are not enough. I would like to break the loop from the else, how can I do?

```
checkFirebase.orderByKey().limitToLast(20).on('child_added', function(snapshot){

    var productRecipe = snapshot.key;
    var amountRecipe = snapshot.child("amount").val() * amountAdded;

    if(productRecipe == productStock){

        if(amountRecipe <= amountStock){
            alert("The amount is enough.");
        }else{
            alert("The quantity is not enough.");
            break;
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: There is no loop in this code, so the `break` won't do anything. What do you expect it to break from?

Comment: I would like it when the code stream goes into the else, the flow is diverted to another place. I'm having a lot of trouble with asynchronous communication in Firebase. I still do not get it right. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop listening the `child_added` event, you can try `Off`.

**Try this:**

```
checkFirebase.orderByKey().limitToLast(20).on('child_added', function(snapshot){

    var productRecipe = snapshot.key;
    var amountRecipe = snapshot.child("amount").val() * amountAdded;

    if(productRecipe == productStock){

        if(amountRecipe <= amountStock){
            alert("The amount is enough.");
        }else{
            alert("The quantity is not enough.");
            checkFirebase.off('child_added');//stop listening to child_added event
        }

    }

});
```

For more information on `off` Please Read [firebase References#off Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off)

Comment: Are you sure it's the `checkFirebase` ref upon which you'd call `off` and not the ref returned by `limitToLast`?

Comment: if you call `off` on `checkFirebase`, it will stop listening for any child_added in `checkFirebase` reference, Do you want that or something else?

Comment: It's just that that's not the reference upon which `on` was called - as `limitToLast` returns a reference with the limit applied. Doesn't look right, that's all.

Comment: `limitToLast` is just a listener to the last 20 child, if there is new child in last 20, it will fire the callback function. So if you want to only listen for child_added in last 20 child, you should call off with limitToLast

Comment: According to official firebase documentation, it should have worked,
`If a callback is not specified, all callbacks for the specified eventType will be removed. Similarly, if no eventType or callback is specified, all callbacks for the Reference will be removed.`